# How to extract a specific row from Panda DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

if I have a dataframe with several row and several columns.

```py
x = {a: (1,2,3),
     b: (4,5,6),
     c: (7,8,9)}
pd.DataFrame(x)
```

it will give out

```
    a   b   c
0   1   4   7
1   2   5   8
2   3   6   9
```

I want to extract the row where the value in column c is specific number

in this case, if the specific number is 8, I need the row 1.

```
1   2   5   8
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it works:

`df[df['c'] == 8]`

Explanation: `df['c'] == 8` produces a boolean mask where the condition is true, then `df[]` selects only them.

Comment: Please add some explanation to that code